# win api c# property grid value

Tags: c#, winapi, propertygrid

How do I get property or tree Grid value in component on 3-th software on my program witch WinAPi? Spy++ and analog return GetWindowText only caption window "PropertyGrid". 
i need read data from other program im my program

Answer (score 0):

The property grid is a custom control and hence you cannot use the GetWindowText function to get its contents. Besides, the property grid shows various data values and not a single block of text so it would not make sense too.

Comment: that mean i cannot elgance and simple read data from Grid wich winapi?
abandon the idea?